# Sum of a self adjoint operator and compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Suppose $A$ is a self adjoint operator and $B$ is a compact operator.

Can we say that $A+B$ is a self-adjoint operator?

Comment: $(A+B)^{\ast} = A^{\ast}+B^{\ast}$, so $A$ is self-adjoint, then $A+B$ is self-adjoint if and only if $B$ is self-adjoint.

Answer (score 4):

No, take $A = 0$ and $B$ any compact operator which is not self-adjoint. For example $B  = i \cdot \mathrm{id}$ on $M_n(\mathbb C)$.